# Sending notification from one app to another app in Android

Tags: android

I am creating android application for sending notification. I have create two Android application. Here I want to send some forms details via notification from first Android application to 2nd android application in Android.

And after that receiving the notification, click on the notification I want to open my second Android application. What should be done to send the push notification to the particular individual user in Android?

Here is my Activity one codes

```
public class Activity_One extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_one);
        Button btn =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.customer.Activity_One","com.vendor.Activity_B"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Here is AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.customer"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_One"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"  />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is Activity two code

```
public class Activity_B extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_two);
        Button bn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1Send);
        bn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction("com.customer.Activity_One");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.vendor"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

         <activity
            android:name=".Activity_B"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action 
                  android:name="com.vendor.Activity_B" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use notifications at all. You can just use intents. That is the standard way to accomplish what you want to achieve. See [Interacting with Other Apps](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/index.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

From first application you can start a normal notification and from second application initialize a broadcast receiver and read notification